# Wordpress meta box saving isn't working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cannot figure out why the events_price and events_location are not saving while events_startdate is.  I've tested this every which way, and it still isn't saving the data.

```
  function event_detail_box_content() {
    global $post;

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $meta_sd = $custom["events_startdate"][0];
    $meta_pr = isset( $custom['events_price'] ) ? esc_attr( $custom["events_price"][0]): ”;
    $meta_lo = $custom["events_location"][0];

    $meta_st = $meta_sd;

    $time_format = get_option('time_format');

    if ($meta_sd == null) { $meta_sd = time(); $meta_st = 0;}

    $clean_sd = date("D, M d, Y", $meta_sd);
    $clean_st = date($time_format, $meta_st);

    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' ); 

    ?>
    <div class="tf-meta">
    <ul>
        <li><label>Event Date</label><input name="events_startdate" class="tfdate" value="<?php echo $clean_sd; ?>" /></li>
        <li><label>Event Time</label><input name="events_starttime" value="<?php echo $clean_st; ?>" /><em>Use 24h format (7pm = 19:00)</em></li>
        <li><label>Event Price</label><input name="events_price" value="<?php echo $meta_pr; ?>" /></li>
        <li><label>Event Location</label><input name="events_location" value="<?php echo $meta_lo; ?>" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
    print_r($custom);
 }

  add_action ('save_post', 'save_events');

 function save_events($post_id){

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return; 

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post')) return;

    if(!isset($_POST["events_startdate"])): return; endif;

    $updatestartd = strtotime ( $_POST["events_startdate"] . $_POST["events_starttime"] );

    update_post_meta($post_id, "events_startdate", $updatestartd ); 

    update_post_meta($post_id, "events_price",  $POST["events_price"] );  

    update_post_meta($post_id, "events_location", $POST["events_location"] ); 
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing underscores on your `$_POST` variables

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "events_price",  $POST["events_price"] );  

update_post_meta($post_id, "events_location", $POST["events_location"] );
```

Should be

```
update_post_meta($post_id, "events_price",  $_POST["events_price"] );  

update_post_meta($post_id, "events_location", $_POST["events_location"] );
```